# Month and Date messed up in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a situation where month and date are messed up for few dates in my dataframe. For e.g here is the input:

```
df['work_date'].head(15)

    0     2018-01-01
    1     2018-02-01
    2     2018-03-01
    3     2018-04-01
    4     2018-05-01
    5     2018-06-01
    6     2018-07-01
    7     2018-08-01
    8     2018-09-01
    9     2018-10-01
    10    2018-11-01
    11    2018-12-01
    12    2018-01-13
    13    2018-01-14
    14    2018-01-15
```

The date is stored as a `string`. As you can see, the date is in the format `yyyy-dd-mm` till 12th of Jan and then becomes `yyyy-mm-dd`. The dataframe consists of 3 years worth data and this pattern repeats for all months for all years.

My expected output is to standardize the date to format `dddd-mm-yy` like below.

```
0     2018-01-01
1     2018-01-02
2     2018-01-03
3     2018-01-04
4     2018-01-05
5     2018-01-06
6     2018-01-07
7     2018-01-08
8     2018-01-09
9     2018-01-10
10    2018-01-11
11    2018-01-12
12    2018-01-13
13    2018-01-14
14    2018-01-15
```

Below is the code that I wrote and it gets the job done. Basically, I split the date string and do some string manipulations. However, as you can see its not too pretty. I am checking to see if there could be some other elegant solution to this other than doing the `df.apply` and the `loops`.

```
def func(x):
    d = x.split('-')
    print(d)
    if (int(d[1]) <= 12) & (int(d[2]) <= 12) :
        d = [d[0],d[2],d[1]]
        x = '-'.join(d)
        return x
    else:
        return x
df['work_date'] = df['work_date'].apply(lambda x:func(x))
```

Comment: where did this data come from?

Comment: Its coming from a third party to us and we dont have much control on how its shared to us

Comment: so are they providing you with a database connection or a CSV file or...?

Comment: its a CSV file which has been accumulated over past few months..

Comment: you mean `yyyy-mm-dd` instead of `dddd-mm-yy`?

Comment: so, for example, there are two rows with "2018-12-01" in the date column?

Comment: personally, I'd have the data provider correct their errors, but that's consulting advice not programming advice

Comment: I would put in no better than @ Paul H ,

Comment: right, but are there two rows with "2018-12-01" in the date field?

Comment: Definitely @PaulH . I agree, thats def one way to fix this. However, thats a long route for us and will take some time. We got this data after some hardship. So we will get push back to clean it ourselves.

Comment: There are no two rows with '2018-12-01' . Just one only..

Comment: @sharathnatraj for future, simply tell the provider not to save the .csv file once it is generated, OR if you have a colleague, tell them not to save the file before sending to you. If a .csv file is generated by a USA user and a UK user opens it and re-saves it (OR vice versa), then the date format can get messed up, so the fundamental problem is that whoever is causing the dates to get messed up -- they should stop overwiting the `.csv` file and send you the original OR they should save that column as TEXT in excel or other solutions.

Comment: Agreed @DavidErickson. I will be communicating this for future. Thanks!! However, for now, I think the onus would be upon my team to get this mess fixed :-( .. I caught this by luck. We are doing some timeseries forecasting with this.

Comment: with three years of data, i would correct it by hand

Comment: You could also use `pandas.date_range` is the data are regularly-spaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just update the column based on the fact that it is in order and there is only one date and all days of the year are included consecutively:

```
df['Date'] = pd.date_range(df['work_date'].min(), '2018-01-12', freq='1D')
# you can specify df['work_date'].min() OR df['work_date'].max) OR A STRING. It really depends on what format your minimum and your maximum is
df
Out[1]: 
     work_date       date
0   2018-01-01 2018-01-01
1   2018-02-01 2018-01-02
2   2018-03-01 2018-01-03
3   2018-04-01 2018-01-04
4   2018-05-01 2018-01-05
5   2018-06-01 2018-01-06
6   2018-07-01 2018-01-07
7   2018-08-01 2018-01-08
8   2018-09-01 2018-01-09
9   2018-10-01 2018-01-10
10  2018-11-01 2018-01-11
11  2018-12-01 2018-01-12
12  2018-01-13 2018-01-13
13  2018-01-14 2018-01-14
14  2018-01-15 2018-01-15
```

To make this more dynamic, you could also do some `try` / `except` shown below:

```
minn = df['work_date'].min()
maxx = df['work_date'].max()
try:
    df['Date'] = pd.date_range(minn, maxx, freq='1D')
except ValueError:
    s = maxx.split('-')
    df['Date'] = pd.date_range(minn, f'{s[0]}-{s[2]}-{s[1]}', freq='1D')
except ValueError:
    s = minn.split('-')
    df['Date'] = pd.date_range(f'{s[0]}-{s[2]}-{s[1]}', maxx, freq='1D')
df
```

Comment: @PaulH thank you. I also thought about it again and thought `date_range` might be the best solution here (I saw your comment about that after I edited my answer).

Comment: really nice one @DavidErickson. I just did `pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2020-12-30', freq='1D')` and its all that I needed!!